# Kotlin: replace 'cascade if' with 'when' comparing with other variables

Tags: android, if-statement, kotlin

I'm starting with Kotlin and I'm facing a problem.
I have three constants (let's call them VAL_A, VAL_B and VAL_C) and I'm doing this assignation:

```
var variable = if (value < VAR_A) {
            valueA
        } else if (value <= VAR_B) {
            valueB
        } else if (value <= VAR_C) {
            valueC
        } else {
            valueD
        }
```

I want to use a when block instead of the if else, but I don't know how to do the value < VAR_A and the value > VAR_C ones.

Thank you and sorry about my English!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The ideal syntax you may be looking for is

```
when (value) {
    < valueA -> valueA
    <= valueB -> valueB
    <= valueC -> valueC
    else -> valueD
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't possible because the [comparison operators are operator overloads](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#comparison) for functions requiring a receiver:

```
value < valueA
```

is the same as

```
value.compareTo(valueA) < 0
```

Because `compareTo` is not a keyword like `is` or `in` (as used in zsmb13's answer), you would need to create this `when` block:

```
when {
    value < valueA -> valueA
    value <= valueB -> valueB
    value <= valueC -> valueC
    else -> valueD
}
```

Kotlin is full of wonderful things. You could adventure into some alternative solutions that don't use a cascading conditional at all. It looks to me like you want `value` to round up to the nearest of `valueA`, `valueB`, `valueC`, and `valueD`. So, for example, an alternative may be:

```
var variable = listOf(valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD).sorted().first { value <= it }
```

This will choose the closest value larger than `value` from the set and assign it to `variable`.

Comment: That was exactly my problem, I didn't know I can use when without a parameter.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12):

This should be the simplest equivalent of your `if` expression:

```
var variable = when {
    value < VAR_A -> valueA
    value <= VAR_B -> valueB
    value <= VAR_C -> valueC
    else -> valueD
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If, for example, it's true that 0 < `VAR_A` < `VAR_B` < `VAR_C`, you could do this:

```
var variable = when (value) {
    in 0..VAR_A -> valueA
    in VAR_A..VAR_B -> valueB
    in VAR_B..VAR_C -> valueC
    else -> valueD
}
```

But perhaps this is the most legible form of `when` for this task:

```
var variable = when {
    value <= VAR_A -> valueA
    value <= VAR_B -> valueB
    value <= VAR_C -> valueC
    else -> valueD
}
```